# Create Search Bar that show data in dropdown menu in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uisearchbar

I'm creating E-Commerce type app where user select zones from the list using textfield.

[image]

I want to that when user click on text Filed and write zone (like 55) and show dropdown all the data from the array which starting to 55 or having number of 5 in array (like 20051).

After showing all data in the form of dropdown. User select desired zone code and added in table view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below to add search bar to UItableviewController and get searchBar on selecting UITextfield.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!

var originalArr = [[String:Any]]();
var searchArrRes = [[String:Any]]()
var searching:Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //Assign delegate  don't forget
     txtName.delegate = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    //my array
    originalArr =   [
        ["name": "abdul", "number": "+8800000001"],
        ["name": "abdin", "number": "+8800000002"],
        ["name": "Enamul", "number": "+8800000003"],
        ["name": "enam", "number": "+8800000004"],
        ["name": "Rafi", "number": "+8800000005"],
        ["name": "Ehaque", "number": "+8800000006"],
        ["name": "ab", "number": "+8800000007"],
        ["name": "Emon", "number": "+8800000008"],
        ["name": "enamu1", "number": "+8800000009"],
        ["name": "rafi", "number": "+88000000010"],
        ["name": "karim", "number": "+88000000011"],
        ["name": "radev", "number": "+88000000012"],
        ["name": "da", "number": "+88000000013"],
        ["name": "aa", "number": "+88000000014"],
        ["name": "rafi", "number": "+88000000010"],
        ["name": "karim", "number": "+88000000011"],
        ["name": "radev", "number": "+88000000012"],
        ["name": "da", "number": "+88000000013"],
        ["name": "aa", "number": "+88000000014"]
    ]
    
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

   public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: 
 NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool{
    //input text
   let searchText  = textField.text! + string
    //add matching text to arrya
    searchArrRes = self.originalArr.filter({(($0["name"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))})
    
    if(searchArrRes.count == 0){
        searching = false
    }else{
        searching = true
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData();
    
    return true
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //check search text & original text
    if( searching == true){
        return searchArrRes.count
    }else{
        return originalArr.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //custom cell Custom_cell
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Custom_cell
    //check search text & original text
    if( searching == true){
        var dict = searchArrRes[indexPath.row]
        cell.label_name.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.label_number.text = dict["number"] as? String
    }else{
        var dict = originalArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.label_name.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.label_number.text = dict["number"] as? String
        
    }
    
    return cell
}


}
```

**CustomCell Class**

```
class Custom_cell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label_name: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label_number: UILabel!
   
 }
```

Comment: Cool!  How does the ViewController know where to put the dropdown menu to select the suggestions?  Does the textField already have that system set up?  Will the drop-down go on top of other objects on the viewController?